# KY Birds...which book is that from.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I am trying to find the name of this mathematical book, a smart student at my university gave a lecture about it a long time ago, and all I can remember of the talk was

- it was about mathematics
- it had birds
- one of the birds had the name KY.

I have tried google to find the title or author; however, searching with KY doesn't result in any thing mathematical.

I am asking here because someone here should know the Title of the book.

Comment: I have no idea what you could possibly mean by either "birds" or "KY" in a mathematical context. Closed.

Comment: @qiaochu yuan The book used the example of birds and one type of the birds was KY...I think it had something to do with algebra.

Comment: To Mock a Mockingbird and Other Logic Puzzles: Including an Amazing Adventure in Combinatory Logic by Raymond Smullyan

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The book name is "To Mock a Mockingbird and Other Logic Puzzles: Including an Amazing Adventure in Combinatory Logic" by Raymond Smullyan.  

I wasn't being vulgar and yes I have tried searching for the book with the information I remembered from the talk.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is this question better?

Comment: @aaa: You should post that as an answer (when the question is reopened). Frankly though, if I hadn't been told about it a few weeks ago I would never have guessed the question had anything to do with combinatory logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book name is "To Mock a Mockingbird and Other Logic Puzzles: Including an Amazing Adventure in Combinatory Logic" by Raymond Smullyan.

> A certain enchanted forest is inhabited by talking birds. Given any
>   birds A and B, if you call out the name of B to A, then A will respond
>   by calling out the name of some bird to you; this bird we designate
>   AB. Thus AB is the bird named by A upon hearing the name of B.

In the beginning, there is about hundred pages with unrelated logic puzzles and the rest of the book (about 200 pages) is about a policeman exploring different forests populated with different combinatory logic birds.

For example, Mockingbird is a combinator M defined

```
M x = x x
```

Bluebird is

```
B x y z = x (y z)
```

and so on ;-)

Comment: Just a note, that this is not as obscure terminology as it seems. There is a self published e-book that uses it. http://combinators.info/ It mostly deals with trying to bring the concepts to programming in Ruby.

Comment: There is even a scientific paper that can be found through scholar.google.com that uses this terminology.