# What was the book about birds and sets?

Tags: reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [KY Birds…which book is that from.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102739/ky-birds-which-book-is-that-from)

Does anyone know the title of the book that taught sets (I think) through examples with the birds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly you’re thinking of Raymond Smullyan’s [*To Mock a Mockingbird*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Mock_a_Mockingbird), though its topic is combinatory logic, not set theory.

Comment: That one was a lot of fun.  It takes you all the way to Godel's incompleteness.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Is there a similar book like this to intro in Category theory?

Comment: @drozzy: I’m not aware of one. There’s definitely not one by Smullyan.